# jQuery to get text of first span of every li

Tags: jquery

I am trying to get the first value of `span` under different `li` elements. My HTML markup is as follows...

```
<div class="mipartrel">
    <div class="k-multiselect-wrap k-floatwrap">
        <ul role="listbox" unselectable="on" class="k-reset">
            <li class="k-button">
                <span>bat</span>
                <span class="k-icon k-delete">delete</span>
            </li>
            <li class="k-button">
                <span>ball</span>
                <span class="k-icon k-delete">delete</span>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

I used the following jQuery code to get the text of all the `span` elements...

```
var getdata=$('.mipartrel ul li span').first().text();
```

...but I am only getting the value `"bat"`. I need each and every value from the first `span` of every `li`.

Comment: you can have look at this http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/

Comment: Try this var getdata=$('.mipartrel ul li span').first().html();

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The `first` method only returns the first matched element, you can use the `find` method:

```
var textArray = $('.mipartrel ul li').find('span:first').map(function(){
    return $(this).text();
}).get(); // ["bat", "ball"]

var textString = textArray.join(); // "bat, ball"
```

http://jsfiddle.net/s797E/

Or:

```
var getdata = $('.mipartrel ul li').find('span:first').text();
```

Comment: thank you. this worked and also the values are seperated by comma thats exactly what i wanted thanks

Comment: @user1001176: Note that the result is an array, not a comma separated string. If you convert the array to a string, it will return the strings from the array as a comma separated string.

Comment: @Guffa thanks clearing this :) Thats why i love this community so much to learn

Answer (score 4):

Use the `first-child` selector to get the spans that are the first child of their parent:

```
var getdata = $('.mipartrel ul li span:first-child').text();
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/38NN5/

The `text` method will get the text from all elements as a single string. If you want it as an array, you need to get each text separately:

```
var getdata = $('.mipartrel ul li span:first-child').map(function(){
  return $(this).text();
}).get();
```

Answer (score -1):

here is [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jhnD5/1/) to get the elements using for loop

```
    $('ul.k-reset li').each(function(){
       var current = $(this).find('span:first');
        alert(current.text());
     });
```